# undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow8OpKernel11TraceStringEPNS_15OpKernelContextEb

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I'm getting the error below:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/daya/Deep_Learning/Keras-Tuner/HiddenLayersAndHiddenNeurons.py

2020-12-22 09:42:14.472136: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/daya/Deep_Learning/Keras-Tuner/HiddenLayersAndHiddenNeurons.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tensorflow import keras
  File "/home/daya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 435, in <module>
    _ll.load_library(_main_dir)

  File "/home/daya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 153, in load_library
    py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(lib)

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/kernels/libtfkernel_sobol_op.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow8OpKernel11TraceStringEPNS_15OpKernelContextEb
```

**System config**:

Ubuntu 18.04,
cuda11.1 cudnn8,
GTX 1660,
Tensorflow-gpu 2.4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 17):

In case this is an issue for you and downgrading Tensorflow is not an option, here is a hack:

delete `tensorflow/core/kernels/libtfkernel_sobol_op.so` altogether. This operator is a special purpose op in classic computer version for edge extraction and for 99.99% of the use cases of TF (training DNN) you won't need this operator.

Comment: This simple quickfix worked for me! I wasted a lot of time trying to find a solution!

Comment: Worked for me when uninstall/install did not! To be on the safe side, I just renamed it to a backup file

Answer (score 12):

Looks like it is the following issue (same symbol `_ZN10tensorflow8OpKernel11TraceStringEPNS_15OpKernelContextEb` is missing): https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/385

Did you try to update Tensorflow?

Comment: Bit annoying, but can you show output of this command `python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'`?

Comment: According to github it looks like a problem only with version 2.3.0, but not 2.4.0.

Comment: I have installed 2.3.0 the problem solved :)

Comment: @dayanand-dhumala Yay. It was nice to help you.

Comment: `pip uninstall tensorflow` to uninstall, and `pip install -U tensorflow==2.3.0` to install a working version.