# Tensorflow docker installation problem. (undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow8OpKernel11TraceStringEPNS_15OpKernelContextEb)

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to learn more about tensorflow and building a custom model with it.

I follow an instruction in which i install a docker container with the following steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
cd models
docker build -f research/object_detection/dockerfiles/tf2/Dockerfile -t od .
docker run -it od
```

All works ok.

Next step is to run a test in the container script:

```
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py
```

This fails and outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 22, in <module>
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
  File "/home/tensorflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 438, in <module>
    _ll.load_library(_main_dir)
  File "/home/tensorflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 154, in load_library
    py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(lib)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/kernels/libtfkernel_sobol_op.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow8OpKernel11TraceStringEPNS_15OpKernelContextEb
```

So there is a question about this in stackoverflow [see:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65405705/undefined-symbol-zn10tensorflow8opkernel11tracestringepns-15opkernelcontexteb)
Also a followup [at:](https://github.com/tensorflow/text/issues/385)

It says, if i understand correctly, to uninstall and install tensorflow again, but it does not work.

The version is 2.6.1. If i try to downgrade i run into all kind of other problems.

I am stuck ;-(, any clues ?

I am working on a VPS, is it possible to run the tensorflow docker on 'normal' hardware ?